# php method for key retrieval

Tags: php

Is there any equivalent **php method** to 'urllib.urlopen()'  for retrieving the public key from any public key server

Comment: You mean _python's_ urlib as described at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html ?

Comment: yeh! this method retrieve the public key from public key server ,in a similar way i need to do it in php.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would use urllib.urlopen() to retrieve the public key?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the contents of a URL with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: problem is to get php method which fetch the public key from public key server